# Creating a new field by Mutating existing Longitude and Latitude fields in ElasticSearch Index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Is it possible to mutate two fields in Kibana Dev. Tools/Console, i.e. Latitude, Longitude into a geo_point type field using existing index and fields which are already imported from MySQL.

The idea is not to re-import all the data from MySQL and going through the Logstash.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to update the mapping to add the geo_point field. Then you can add the geo_point field to each document off a scroll request, using the latitude-longitude fields and bulk update the docs.

Bulk API: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bulk.html

Scroll: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

Comment: Can you give examples of mapping via Console (Dev. Tools) that would be very helpful.

Comment: you'll find it here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html

Comment: Is there an example where they added a geopoint field to existing documents in an index?

Comment: `PUT index/type/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "field_name": {
      "type": "geo_point"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: okay, its added, now I just want to add lat and lon to the "location" field i just added, any ideas as to how to go about that?